# How to define a byte array use the string style in .net?

Tags: c#, encoding

I want define a byte array like `"\x90<>"`,

I can only define it use numbers

`byte[] a = new byte[] { 0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e };`

but it's not readable and cost more time to write,

Can I do something like this in .net?

`byte[] a = '\x90<>';`

---

Edited.

I'm ask this because in c and c++ I can actually define a byte array by

`char myvar[] = "\x90<>";` or `char *myvar= "\x90<>";`

they are equals `new byte[] { 0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e}` on c#.

Comment: characters in C# are not bytes

Comment: yes, range of char is 0-65535 and byte is 0-255, I just want the style like this.

Comment: You can create a custom converter to convert from your format to hex format

Comment: I'm a little lost as to why \x is equal to 0x90?

Comment: You can read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, OP keeps the items that can't convert to visible characters as literal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to byte array as this.

```
 string source = "\x90<>";
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(source);
```

Comment: It's not correct, result is `0x63, 0x60, 0x62`, and I except `0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e`.

Comment: Did you checked the result of `new byte[] { 0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e };`?

Comment: -new byte[] { 0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e } {byte[3]} byte[]
[0] 144 byte
[1] 60 byte
[2] 62 byte
-Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\x90<>") {byte[3]} byte[]
[0] 144 byte
[1] 60 byte
[2] 62 byte

Answer (score 1):

A `string` is an array of `char`s, where a char is not a `byte` in the .Net.

You can't define `byte`s with a `string` and you can't do this in easy way, you must implement your own convertor methods and use it with that.

Check this out:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it to a char array in the declaration. The escaped characters will be correctly processed into a single char and the unescaped characters will be split into individual characters.

Then you can cast each element in the array as a byte. You could use LINQ to make it easy:

```
var bytes = "\x90<>".ToCharArray().Select(b => (byte)b);
foreach(var myByte in bytes){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0x{0:x2}", myByte));
}
```

I believe this gives you the correct output of `0x90, 0x3c, 0x3e`

### Edit

I'm sure there will be some issue with encoding here, but none was specified in the question.

### Extra Edit

The code above will give you an `IEnumerable<byte>`. To get the actual `byte[]` you want, just call

```
bytes.ToArray();
```